# Calculate maximum average block points

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, average

I have an array with 30.000 integer values, and I need to calculate the biggest 60 consecutive elements block. I've done this, it works but I don't know if there is a better way to do that. Now it costs around 4 seconds with 30.000 points.

```
$values = array();
$max = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 30000; $i++) {
    $values[] = rand(0, 1000);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 29940; $i++) {
    $subValues = array_slice($values, $i, 60);
    $sum = array_sum($subValues);
    $avg = $sum / 60;
    $max = ($avg > $max) ? $avg : $max;
}

$maxValues = array_slice($values, $max, 60);
```

Comment: One small tweak I can see is that you don't need to calculate the average. You can just use the largest sum.

Comment: You don't need to sum repeatedly; you just need to adjust the edges as you traverse the data block. Sum the [0-59], record that total and the location 0. Now delete from that total the zeroth element and add element 60. Replace the stored total and the location (1) if this block has a higher total. Then subtract element 1 and add element 61 etc. etc. i.e. repeat until you get to the end of the block. I'm not a php programmer so can't really give an answer but my idea is, I think, the fastest. Drop the location if you're not interested in where the maximum block lies.

Comment: Thank you so much Bathsheba, it worked like a charm. Going down from 4 seconds to 0.02!!! And I tried for 1 million elements and 0.7 seconds... GREAT!!! :D

Comment: @user2564750 are you sure ?  can you add your new code to the answer or update your question

Comment: @Baba Here it is: [http://pastebin.com/0zxWR4M3](http://pastebin.com/0zxWR4M3)

Comment: @user2564750 ok good .... I found out that `array_slice` alone took 3.2 sec in your last code .... that was the real bottle neck